# SQL decode statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'am supposed to write a sql statement with decode. The Result should look like:

```
1   CHF 1
2   USD 1.003985
```

And that's my code which I have written.

```
SELECT distinct
        CCY.ORDER_KEY,
        CCY.ISO_CODE,
     decode(   NVL(POS.CCY_RATE_ASK, POS.SECURITY_CCY_RATE_ASK),
        decode (POS_CCY_ID,CCY_ID, CCY_RATE_ASK,
                           SECURITY_CCY_ID,SECURITY_CCY_RATE_ASK,
                           SECURITY_PRICE_CCY_ID,SECURITY_PRICE_CCY_RATE_ASK),CCY_RATE_ASK) rate                    
 FROM   AO_CCY_TEST POS,
        CURRENCIES CCY
 WHERE  1=1 --POS.LIMIT_MOTHER_CST_ID=p_CST_ID
 AND    1=1 --POS.CONS_PRD=P_CONS_PRD_ID
 AND    1=1 --POS.POS_STATUS!=10
 AND    POS.POS_CCY_ID=CCY.ID
 ORDER  BY CCY.ORDER_KEY;
```

My current result is:

```
1   CHF 1
2   USD 1.003985
2   USD
```

Iam not supposed to change anything in the were clause

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? They're different databases, please tag the one you're actually using only

Comment: Can you first prvide the content of `AO_CCY_TEST` and `CURRENCIES`? Furthermore why do you write `1=1`?

Comment: Maybe this query can be a subquery with `rate is not null`.

Comment: What century are you living in?  `decode()` was long ago replaced by the ANSI standard `case`.  Commas in the `FROM` clause have been out of style for decades.